# How to compare two float values in ksh?

Tags: ksh, floating-point

To compare float values below command is working fine in bash, But not working in ksh on AIX.

```
if (( $(bc <<< " 5.3 >= 5.3") ));then echo "hi";else echo "bye";fi`,
```

I had tried in so many ways, can someone suggest me to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for your answers,It helped me. Till now I was using `if [[ 5.3 > 5.3 ]] || [[ 5.3 == 5.3 ]];then echo "hi";else echo "bye";fi` In this [[ 5.3 == 5.3 ]], was working fine but I didn't get why It not working for >= or <=.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [POSIX standard for bc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html):

> Unlike all other operators, the relational operators ( '<', '>', "<=", ">=", "==", "!=" ) shall be only valid as the object of an if, while, or inside a for statement.

It appears to be a GNU/Linux extension to allow bare comparisons to evaluate to true or false.

Instead of checking bc's output for 1 or 0, just use `test` directly:

```
if [ 5.3 -ge 5.3 ]; then echo hi; else echo bye; fi
```

or use arithmetic expansion (ksh93):

```
if (( 5.3 >= 5.3 )); then echo hi; else echo bye; fi
```

or use awk:

```
if awk -v x=5.3 -v y=5.3 'BEGIN { exit (x >= y) ? 0 : 1 }'; then echo hi; else echo bye; fi
```

Comment: Will that really work in `ksh` on AIX? In `ksh93` that produces "arithmetic syntax error".

Comment: I get "hi" from both; you get the error with the `((` version?

Comment: After a bit of investigation, my issue with not being able to do floating point arithmetics (or even floating point assignments) may be local issue with the `ksh93` that I'm using (`ksh93` from the `ksh93-20120801p1` package on OpenBSD 6.1).

Comment: #jeff Schaller, last one is working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the values like this:

```
$ fat=5.3
$ slim=5.3
$ echo $fat'>'$slim | bc -l
0
$ echo $fat'>'$slim | bc -l
0
$ echo $fat'=='$slim |bc -l
1
```

Output: `0`=false and `1`=true

Comment: Except on AIX, whose `bc` does not support bare relational expressions (unlike GNU/Linux's bc)

Comment: [Relational expressions are a special kind of expression that always evaluate to 0 or 1, 0 if the relation is false and 1 if the relation is true. These may appear in any legal expression. (POSIX bc requires that relational expressions are used only in if, while, and for statements and that only one relational test may be done in them.)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html)

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm on FreeBSD and it is working. On `man bc` it is mentioned `AUTHORS The original version of the bc command was written by Robert Morris and Lorinda Cherry.  The current version of the bc utility was written by Otto Moerbeek`, therefore I feel like FreeBSD is using the original UNIX implementation of `bc`

Comment: I pointed out the difference due to the OP's [aix] tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dc` utility for doing `math` in shell. The command will print a `hi` to `stdout` when $n1 >= $n2, otherwise a `bye` shall be displayed.

```
n1=5.3 n2=5.3
dc -e "[[hi]]sa [r]sb $n1 $n2 !>a [bye] z2=bp"
```

---

```
       $n1  $n2   o/p
 1.    5.3, 5.3 => hi
 2.    5.3, 5.2 => hi
 3.    5.3, 5.4 => bye
```